# For what are "not an answer" flags and what are "not questions"?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

*Edit: Actually, when I talk about a "not a question" flag I talk about a flag for "in need of moderator intervention" with the text "this is not a question"*

So I have flagged some questions and answers lately with "Not an answer" and "Not a question" flags, it seems however, my definition of "not an answer" and "not a question" is different from the moderators one. I am not sure how you define "not an answer" but for me, not an answer is not only spam but also some explanation which doesn't even try to answer the question but talks about something completely different.

Example #1: [is it acceptable to use ob_start()/ob_clean/ob_flush() to do error handling in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926040/is-it-acceptable-to-use-ob-start-ob-clean-ob-flush-to-do-error-handling-in-p/28926158#28926158)

The TE asks whether it is okay to do error-handling with `ob_start`, `ob_clean` and `ob_flush`. The Answer explains what the three functions do. I flagged the answer as "not an answer". Sure, it might answer some different question, but not the asked one. It doesn't even try to answer the asked question, so for me this is *not an answer for that particular question*.

Example #2: [Why is the finally statement needed if there is no catch block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040427/why-is-the-finally-statement-needed-if-there-is-no-catch-block/35040575#35040575)

The question asks **why** can't you have a `try` block without `catch` and `finally`. The answer just explains, that you can not have a `try` without a `catch` or a `finally`. This **does not answer this question at all**. The flag got declined.

So for me it seems like you can talk about the topic the TE asks about whatever you want to talk about, it is still considered an "answer" for SO, even though it does not try to answer the question.

I also flagged a question as "not a question" recently: [The device cannot run executables for arm64. - Xcode 8 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37893500/the-device-cannot-run-executables-for-arm64-xcode-8-beta)

The flag got declined. I don't get it. Thats definitely not a question. It's an answer or some explanation about something, but *not a question*. Are the "not an answer" and "not a question" flags even any useful (apart from flagging "thank you" answers)? If answers which are not answers should not be flagged as "not an answer" and questions which are not questions should not be flagged as "not a question", for what are these flags? For everything else we have other flags like "spam", but I flag spam-answers as "spam", not as "not a answer", the same goes for questions.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue

Comment: *The Answer explains what the three functions do* A wrong answer does not mean it's *not an answer*. Use the down-vote button for incorrect answers. Flagging should be reserved for instances where the text *literally has nothing at all to do with answering the question*.

Answer (score 1):

Your Not an Answer flag may have been declined because the answer appears to answer the question, especially if you're not an expert in the subject.

The other thing to consider is that the question is a mess. It wasn't clear at first if they were asking about how to fix the problem (given the error message) or if they were asking a language design question.

---

As for the other flag, I don't think you understand exactly what moderator flags are for. Moderator flags are used for the times when [diamond moderator privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75192) are needed to handle the situation.

[Fun fact] There *was* a Not a Real Question close reason:

[image: NARQ]

It's no longer an option. In your case, the "Unclear what you're asking" reason is perfect:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page for help clarifying this question.